# replaceObjectAtIndex error?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

The following code:

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 20];
[kkk replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject: @"cat"];
```

yields this

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   ' -
>  [NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 10
>   beyond bounds for empty array' Call stack at first throw:

Comment: The problem here is you are trying to replace an object which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

`arrayWithCapacity:` allocates the required memory but it doesn't fill the array with objects. `nil` isn't a valid object to fill the array. So if you need an array with empty objects, you will have to do something like this,

```
int size = 20;
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:size];
for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    [kkk addObject:[NSNull null]];
}
```

Now you can safely replace objects,

```
[kkk replaceObjectAtIndex:10 withObject: @"cat"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting an array with that capacity does not fill it with elements; it's still an empty array when you try to replace the object at index 10.  If you provide more detail as to the context in which this is happening, I can try to suggest a way around the problem.

EDIT: if you must have an array with objects right away, try this:

```
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arraywithObjects: @"", @"", @"", @"", nil];
```

except with 20 `@""`'s instead of four.  Then you get an array of 20 strings.  Be sure to put `retain` on the end of it if you're using it outside the immediate scope, though, since `arrayWithObjects` returns an autoreleased array.

Comment: I am trying to avoid dynamically building an array by specifying it's size up front.  After that, then I will fill the array.  Maybe there are better routines to call to fill?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid dynamically building it?  Can you explain what it's going to hold, and how it's being filled?

Comment: For time purpose, I don't want to dynamically build.  I want to init the size upfront and specify the elements to place at each index.

Comment: if you are specifying the elements to place at each index, then you can start with index 0 by using addObject: method.